# Progressive matrix where each box has a dot in a different location

Tags: pattern, visual, progressive-matrix

[image: puzzle]

I tried many hours but can't figure this out
This question is from http://tr.iq-test.cc/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is:

> ... to imagine that the circle is bouncing against the edges.  [image: Graph]